# Unable to install yum-config-manager

Tags: unix, yum

While installing ansible I am getting below error -

```
https://packages.microsoft.com/rhel/7/mssql-server/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] curl#60 - "Peer's certificate issuer has been marked as not trusted by the user."
```

So I tried to run the yum-configure-manager to disable the check however to install yum-utilities I am also getting the same error . 
How to install yum-config-manager 
Basically any yum install is failing with the above mentioned error

Answer (score 3):

You can try installing the package by disabling the certificate check.

To disable certificate check, add following line in /etc/yum.conf:

```
sslverify=false
```

Then try **yum install yum-utils**